# ¿Cómo usar NewRequest en golang?

Tags: go, echo

Tengo 2 funciones, la primera (CreateCotization) consume la segunda que me retorna una url pero al parecer no puedo usarla como string

```
func CreateCotization(c echo.Context) (err error) {
endpoint := "createCotizacionExpress"
urlData := URLConstruction(c, endpoint, "qa")

URL := urlData.(string) // El error que arroja es: urlData (variable of type error) cannot have dynamic type string (missing method Error)

method := "POST"
r := http.NewRequest(method, urlData, nil)

c.JSON(http.StatusOK, r)
return
}
```

en la funcion URLConstruction obtengo los datos y me entrega la url completa con el endpoint

```
func URLConstruction(c echo.Context, endpoint string, ambiente string) (err error) {

if endpoint == "" {
    log.Println("Endpoint can not be blanc")
    return nil
}

if ambiente == "qa" {
    baseURL := "https://servicios.com.mx:9004/Emision/services/"
    doc := baseURL + endpoint

    c.String(http.StatusOK, doc)
    return nil

} else if ambiente == "pro" {
    baseURL := "https://portal.mx:9004/Emision/services/"
    doc := baseURL + endpoint

    c.String(http.StatusOK, doc)
    return

} else {
    return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Url invalida")
}
}
```

El problema es que no puedo tratar la variable urlData como una string, por lo cual no puedo usar el método NewRequest.

Answer (score 1):

Voy a intentar ayudarte aquí.

El problema principal que veo es que tu función URLConstruction devuelve un error.

Recuerda que GoLang es multiparametros por lo que puedes devolver (string, error).

Además de esto te vas a tener que levantar un Client, hacer la pegada y leer la respuesta, no entiendo que quieres hacer con el c.JSON(200,r) , vos estas haciendo una pegada por lo que deberías leer la respuesta, ahi estas creando un JSON para respuesta.

Además veo que quieres crear una cotización y obviamente esta cotización va a llevar unos params en el post, aquí te creo un body de ejemplo con un attribute solo, sentite libre de agregar los que quieras

Lo haría algo asi :

```
func CreateCotization() error {
    endpoint := "createCotizacionExpress"
    urlData, err := URLConstruction(endpoint, "qa")
    var jsonStr = []byte(`{"attr1":"value1"}`)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", urlData, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println("response Status:", resp.Status)
    fmt.Println("response Headers:", resp.Header)
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println("response Body:", string(body))
    return nil
}

func URLConstruction(endpoint string, ambiente string) (string, error) {

    if endpoint == "" {
        err := errors.New("Endpoint cannot be null")

        return "", err
    }

    if ambiente == "qa" {
        baseURL := "https://servicios.com.mx:9004/Emision/services/"
        doc := baseURL + endpoint
        return doc, nil

    } else if ambiente == "pro" {
        baseURL := "https://portal.mx:9004/Emision/services/"
        doc := baseURL + endpoint
        return doc, nil

    } else {
        err := errors.New("Invalid scope")

        return "", err
    }
}
```